# Http cookie store in Android

Tags: java, android, cookies, httpclient

I am developing an Android client for the site with authorization. I have a post method. Example my code:

```
public void run() {
    handler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(handler, HttpConnection.DID_START));
    httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpClient.getParams(), 25000);
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try{            
        switch (method){
        case POST:
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setHeaders(headers);
            if (data != null) httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(data));
            response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            break;
        }
        processEntity(response);

    }catch(Exception e){
        handler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(handler, HttpConnection.DID_ERROR, e));

    }
    ConnectionManager.getInstanse().didComplete(this);      
}
```

How to keep cookies?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You get your cookies from `HttpResponse response`:

```
Header[] mCookies = response.getHeaders("cookie");
```

and add them to your next request:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

//parse name/value from mCookies[0]. If you have more than one cookie, a for cycle is needed.
CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
Cookie cookie = new BasicClientCookie("name", "value");
cookieStore.addCookie(cookie);

HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);

HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.domain.com/"); 

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
```

Comment: this line error `Cookie cookie = BasicClientCookie("name", "value");`. may be use `Cookie cookie =  new BasicClientCookie("name", "value");`?

Comment: Yes, my mistake, forgot the `new` keyword.

Comment: String mCookies[] must be Header[] mCookies otherwise it will be a typecast issue.