# How to maintain server login throughout the android native application?

Tags: android, json, session, cookies, authentication

Let me describe my application ,
I am fetching data from the website JSON url (Drupal website) , data is in JSON format. 
In my application login functionality works perfectly . & user is validated on the server.
I am also fetching other data(JSON url) from the server & displaying in my android application.
**Now, the problem is that I can’t access JSON data of pages , where login is required , because my login is not maintaining throughout the android application.**

I have searched on stackoverflow & google I got these links & tried but don't know how to use them in my code:
http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/statemgmt.html

[Android session management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224913/android-session-management)

[Http cookie store in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133329/http-cookie-store-in-android)

***Here is the Empty JSON that is from drupal site without login.***

```
{
    "nodes": []
}
```

Here is the JSON from drupal site- **after login**(http://www.mywebsite.com/user/login) & reload the page http://www.mywebsite.com/myaccount-page   on the site - in **computer webbrowser** . means **computer web browser automatically maintains the login session.**

```
{
"nodes": [
    {
        "node": {
            "Uid": "51",
            "Username": "anand",
            "Name": "anand",
            "Address": "\n\tAt- vadodara Nr. Kareli Baugh",
            "Date of Birth": "1998-08-20",
            "Occupation": "student",
            "Member Since": "36 weeks 6 days"
        }
    }
 ]
}
```

**But in android application it does not do this automatically.**
***So I want to maintain this session in Android so that I can login in android application , after login redirect to another page-activity & get JSON data there.***
Here is my code:

**LoginActivity.java**

```
     public void onClick(View v) {


            String uName = editUser.getText().toString();
            String Password = editPass.getText().toString();

            if(uName.equals("") | Password.equals(""))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter the Username and Password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{


                                     String strResponse = util.makeWebCall(loginURL,uName,Password);
                 System.out.println("=========> Response from login page=> " + strResponse);


                try{
                    if (strResponse.substring(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                        txterror.setText("");



                         Intent inlogin = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                                post_myprofile.class);
                        inlogin.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(inlogin);

                        //finish();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        txterror.setText("Username and Password Not valid !!!");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }





            }


        }
    });

    btngotoregister.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    RegisterActivity.class);
            // intent.setFlags (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent1);

        }
    });
 }
 }
```

makeWebCall method in util.java

**util.java**

```
 public static String makeWebCall(String url, String uname,String pass)
{
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

     List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

     params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",uname));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",pass));

    UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = null;
    try {
        formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    post.setEntity(formEntity);

    try {
        //post.setEntity(new StringEntity(requestString));

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        System.out.println("=========> Responsehello => "+response);
        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
        {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream is = entity.getContent();
            return iStream_to_String(is);
        }
        else
        {
            return "Hello This is status ==> :"+String.valueOf(statusCode);
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Now with this code login is successful & I got the JSON response from the server with detail.
& page-activity redirects to 2nd page for user profile.
On **2nd page I am not getting the userprofile JSON data-As mentioned above , I am getting Blank JSON because session is not maintained.**

Here is the code of the 2nd page-activity.

**post_myprofile.java**

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String url = "http://www.cheerfoolz.com/myaccount-page";
        String strResponse = util.makeWebCall(url);

        try {
            JSONObject objResponse = new JSONObject(strResponse);

            JSONArray jsonnodes = objResponse
                        .getJSONArray(API.cheerfoolz_myprofile.NODES);
```

makewebcall method for profile in util.java

util.java

```
 public static String makeWebCall(String url) {

    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(url);
  //  HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

    try {

        HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(httpRequest);

         final int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

         if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
          /*  Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                "Error => " + statusCode + " => for URL " + url);*/
            return null;
         }

         HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            InputStream is = entity.getContent();
            return iStream_to_String(is);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        httpRequest.abort();
      // Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error for URL =>" + url, e);
    }

    return null;

 }


public static String iStream_to_String(InputStream is1)
{
     BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is1), 4096);
     String line;
     StringBuilder sb =  new StringBuilder();
     try {
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
         }
         rd.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     String contentOfMyInputStream = sb.toString();
     return contentOfMyInputStream;
}


}
```

**I am getting blank JSON here in this page - that I have mentioned above. so how to maintain session in this user profile activity & get the data?**

Thanks For listening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

finally Its working for me :)

instead of using new **DefaultHttpClient** all the time , I have made it static & used just once.

```
static DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. This was of great help  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.velmurugan.vazbo_new.utility;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.CookieSyncManager;
import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpException;
import org.apache.http.HttpRequest;
import org.apache.http.HttpRequestInterceptor;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponseInterceptor;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.cookie.Cookie;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
/**
 * Created by velsans@gmail.com on 11/1/2015.
 */
public class SessionParser {
    public SessionParser(){
    }
    public static String makeWebCall(String url,List<NameValuePair> params  )
    {
        CommonClass.httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
        UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = null;
        try {
            formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        post.setEntity(formEntity);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = CommonClass.httpClient.execute(post);
            System.out.println("=========> Responsehello => "+response);
            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
            {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream is = entity.getContent();
                return iStream_to_String(is);
            }
            else
            {
                return "Hello This is status ==> :"+String.valueOf(statusCode);
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    public static String makeWebCall(String url) {
        System.out.println("=========> Response url => "+url);
        HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(url);
        try {
            HttpResponse httpResponse = CommonClass.httpClient.execute(httpRequest);
            final int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
          /*  Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                "Error => " + statusCode + " => for URL " + url);*/
                return null;
            }
            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            InputStream is = entity.getContent();
            return iStream_to_String(is);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            httpRequest.abort();
            // Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error for URL =>" + url, e);
        }
        return null;
    }
    public static String iStream_to_String(InputStream is1)
    {
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is1), 4096);
        String line;
        StringBuilder sb =  new StringBuilder();
        try {
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            rd.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String contentOfMyInputStream = sb.toString();
        return contentOfMyInputStream;
    }
}
```