# Android HttpUrlConnection and specific site logging

Tags: android

Can anyone help me in writing a program that will connect to site, log me in, and get content of the logged site? I want it to work for site http://www.imperiaonline.org
There are so many redirects and POST requests that I don't know if it is possible. Please help me.

I've tried something like this, but it doesn't work...

```
    dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
    store = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

    String uRL = "http://www.imperiaonline.org";

    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    Log.v("Execute", "execute url:" + uRL);
    try {
        URL url = new URL(uRL);
        HttpURLConnection httpconn = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();

        if (sCookie != null && sCookie.length() > 0) {
            httpconn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", sCookie);
        }

        if (httpconn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(httpconn.getInputStream()), 8192);
            String strLine = null;
            while ((strLine = input.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(strLine);
            }
            input.close();
        }

        String headerName = null;
        for (int i = 1; (headerName = httpconn.getHeaderFieldKey(i)) != null; i++) {
            if (headerName.equalsIgnoreCase(SET_COOKIE)) {
                Map<String, String> cookie = new HashMap<String, String>();
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(
                        httpconn.getHeaderField(i), COOKIE_VALUE_DELIMITER);

                // the specification dictates that the first name/value pair
                // in the string is the cookie name and value, so let's
                // handle
                // them as a special case:

                if (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    String token = st.nextToken();
                    String name = token.substring(0,
                            token.indexOf(NAME_VALUE_SEPARATOR));
                    String value = token.substring(
                            token.indexOf(NAME_VALUE_SEPARATOR) + 1,
                            token.length());
                    store.add(cookie);
                    cookie.put(name, value);
                }

                while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    String token = st.nextToken();
                    cookie.put(
                            token.substring(0,
                                    token.indexOf(NAME_VALUE_SEPARATOR))
                                    .toLowerCase(),
                            token.substring(
                                    token.indexOf(NAME_VALUE_SEPARATOR) + 1,
                                    token.length()));
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < store.size(); ++i) {
        for (String element : store.get(i).keySet()) {
            Log.i("ARR", element);
        }
    }
    Log.i("HTML", response.toString());


    try {
        StringBuilder postDataBuilder = new StringBuilder().append("uname=").append(URLEncoder.encode("zygmunter", "UTF8"));
        postDataBuilder.append("password=").append(URLEncoder.encode("zygmunter", "UTF8"));
        byte[] postData = null;
        postData = postDataBuilder.toString().getBytes();

        URL url = new URL("http://www99.imperiaonline.org/imperia/game_v5/game/ajax_login.php");
        HttpURLConnection co = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        co.setDoOutput(true);
        co.setRequestMethod("POST");
        co.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postData.length));
        co.setUseCaches(false);

        OutputStream out = co.getOutputStream();
        out.write(postData);
        out.close();

        response = new StringBuilder();
        if (co.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(co.getInputStream()), 8192);
            String strLine = null;
            while ((strLine = input.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(strLine);
            }
            input.close();
        }
        String resp = response.toString();
        Log.i("WYNIK", resp);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://sarangasl.blogspot.fi/2011/06/android-login-screen-using-httpclient.html) example.

```
private HttpClient mHttpClient;
private HttpContext mContext;
private CookieStore mCookieStore;

public void post(){
        ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair> list = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
        list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uname", "your username"));
        list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "your username"));
        list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("form_submit", "Login"));
        task mTask = new task();
        mTask.execute(list);
    }
    public class task extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>... arg0) {
            if(mHttpClient == null){
               mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
             }
             if(mContext == null){
                mContext = new BasicHttpContext();
             }
             if(mCookieStore == null){
                 mCookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
             }
            mContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, mCookieStore)
            String sResponse = "";
            HttpResponse response = null;
            try{

                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www99.imperiaonline.org/imperia/game_v5/game/ajax_login.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(arg0[0]));
                mHttpClient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY, CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);
                response = mHttpClient.execute(httppost, mContext);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
                StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
                while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    s = s.append(sResponse);
                }

                // Getting cookies 
                ArrayList<Cookie> list = new ArrayList<Cookie>(mCookieStore.getCookies());
                for(Cookie cookie : list){
                   Log.i(TAG, "cookie: " + cookie.getName());
                }
            }catch(IOException e){

            }
            return sResponse;
        }

        @Override 
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            System.out.println(result);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you noticed that in post request there's also parameter auth that I cannot find where does it come from...

Comment: As a response I get only simple javascript with redirect. I guess I have to collect cookies from login page, login with this post request and then using collected cookies get the content of page that I received redirect to. Am I right? Sorry for such an obious question, but cookies and so on always were magic for me ;) Maybe you know any good page that explains them.

Comment: Hi, the cookies are stored in mCookieStore. I modifyed the code to show how to get cookie values form cookiestore. Here is also another way to get cookies: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8133462/1888162 here is also useful information: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/trunk/httpclient/src/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientCustomContext.java