# Android - Keep user logged between activities

Tags: java, android

In my app I've a first activity that allow you to login to a web service. If the server allow user to connect it should call a TabHost activity. In TabHost activity I've 3 different activity:

- HomeActivity: it display just a webview
- HistoryActivity: it should display a ListView in which I insert the notification history
- SettingsActivity: it display some settings of the app

In HistoryActivity I've to call to a web service to download a list of the notification history. To call this service I've to keep user logged, how I can do that?

I'm using the following code to connect to history service:

```
public void postData(String url) {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

    try {
        StringEntity  jsonSend = new StringEntity("{\"history\": true}");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        httpPost.setEntity(jsonSend);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        for (String line = null; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
            builder.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        String json = builder.toString();
        Log.d("HISTORY", json);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I used it for login and it works great. To connect to login service I use the following code:

```
public void postData(final String username, final String password) {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pollingId", "XXXXXXXXX"));

        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        for (String line = null; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
            builder.append(line).append("\n");
        }

        String json = builder.toString();

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        Boolean success = jsonObject.getBoolean("success");

        if (success == true) {
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ACCESSO EFFETTUATO!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TabBarActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
       Log.d("CLIENT EXCEPTION", "ERRORE: " + e);
    }catch (IOException e) {
       Log.d("I/O EXCEPTION", "ERRORE: " + e);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If I use it to get notification history the JSON said me that user is not logged. How I can fix it? Thank you

**UPDATE**
I tried to follow your suggestions, but I've the same result. The modified code is the follow:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public void postData(final String username, final String password) {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://extranet.gruppotesta.it/srv/at-brain/login.jsp");

        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pollingId", "XXXXXXX"));

            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            for (String line = null; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
                builder.append(line).append("\n");
            }

            String json = builder.toString();

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            Boolean success = jsonObject.getBoolean("success");

            if (success == true) {
                Header[] cookie = response.getHeaders("cookie");
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putString("cookie", cookie.toString());
                editor.commit();
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ACCESSO EFFETTUATO!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TabBarActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
           Log.d("CLIENT EXCEPTION", "ERRORE: " + e);
        }catch (IOException e) {
           Log.d("I/O EXCEPTION", "ERRORE: " + e);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**HistoryActivity.java**

```
   public void postData(String url) {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String stringCookie = sharedPreferences.getString("cookie", null);
        BasicCookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
        Cookie cookie = new BasicClientCookie("login", stringCookie);
        cookieStore.addCookie(cookie);

        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        try {
            StringEntity jsonRequest = new StringEntity("{\"history\": true}");
            httpPost.setEntity(jsonRequest);
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            httpPost.setHeader("Cookie", cookie.toString());

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            for (String line = null; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
                builder.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            String json = builder.toString();
            Log.d("HISTORY", json);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run the app the server answer me with error "User not logged". What's wrong in my code?

Comment: where have you reached so far ?

Answer (score 1):

When you first login, the web service must provide you with some sort of access token - a valid *user id* perhaps. You need to store and retrieve this *user id* in a [`SharedPreference`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). This *user id* must be passed as a parameter to all subsequent web services to indicate that the user is indeed logged in.

The official tutorial for how to get and set a `SharedPreference` is [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html).

Comment: It's wrong the answer of Jelle van Es: use the cookie?

Comment: You must use `SharedPreferece`s, that's the best way. see edited answer

Comment: I update my question, I hope you can help me to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use CookieStore to store a cookie with the login credentials. Take a look at this link: [Http cookie store in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133329/http-cookie-store-in-android).

Answer (score 0):

Does your service give back a session cookie after successful login?  If so you should store the cookie that the service issues after a login (in the Set-Cookie header in the response from the server) and set this cookie for any future HTTP requests.

```
httpPost.setHeader("Cookie", COOKIE_FROM_SERVER_AFTER_LOGIN);
```

You could use a [CookieStore](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/CookieStore.html) as well to help you store the cookies from HTTP requests - this will make cookie and session management easier.

**UPDATE**

Server headers won't include a `Cookie` header but a `Set-Cookie` header (because the server is instructing your useragent/browser/client to set a cookie and it's this cookie that will be included in your `Cookie` headers) so change this line:

```
response.getHeaders("cookie");
```

to

```
response.getHeaders("set-cookie");
```

**UPDATE:**

Your revision is now pulling out the correct `Set-Cookie` header but you are incorrectly storing the value (you are storing the entire header as the cookie when all you need is the value).

```
if (success == true) {

    Header[] cookies = response.getHeaders("set-cookie");
    //at this point cookies looks like this:
    //Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=84DB43CE8CABC52EBDF777BC0EA96D0F; Path=/; Secure
    //if you just do cookies.toString() like you were doing before it will also include
    //the cookie header which will create an incorrect cookie value.
    //you just need the value of the Set-Cookie header and store that as your cookie
    if (cookies.length > 0){

        //it is very possible for a server to return more than one Set-Cookie header so the proper
        //way would be to iterate through all of the values and string them together
        //in the correct synatax of
        //so you might want to store all of the values as a list in sharedPreferences
        //and let your cookie store put them all in the request for you

        String finalCookie = "";

        for (Header header: cookies){

            //access the value from the Header object and nothing else
            //JSESSIONID=90D84EF5D5BD1C4008F332F9EDA8F9AA; Path=/; Secure;
            if (header.getValue().contains(";")){
                finalCookie += String.format("%s; ", header.getValue().split(";")[0]);
            } else {
                finalCookie += String.format("%s; ", header.getValue());
            }
        }
        //finalCookie = JSESSIONID=1B70CAB822430E14991E14ACAE153F5D; 

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("cookie", finalCookie);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

Now in your StoredPreferences you will have correctly formatted cookies (in your case you are only returning one from your server but it's likely that more than one `Set-Cookie` header can be included in a server response.  So this implementation parses out each cookie and builds a cookie string in the correct format.

Since we are now correctly building the cookie string ourselves you can remove the CookieStore and just pull the "cookie" value out of SharedPreferences and use the string that is returned in your `setHeader` call:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String stringCookie = sharedPreferences.getString("cookie", "");
...
httpPost.setHeader("Cookie", cookie);
```

Keep in mind that although this implementation will work for you it won't take into consideration if cookies change throughout your session.  Since you are the author of the web application you should be aware of whether or not cookies change - maybe when you log in it's the only time you will be given cookies to set in the browser and this solution will work for you.  But a more robust solution will be to save out all of the cookies individually (instead of using editor.putString you can use [editor.putStringSet](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putStringSet(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E)) to save out all of the cookie headers) then when you want to build a cookie for the respond you can .add() each individual cookie to the cookie store and then use the cookie store the same way you were before.  This way each cookie by name is stored individually so that if you ever get another `Set-Cookie` header again for a cookie that you already have loaded in your client it will correctly overwrite that value with the updated cookie value.

Comment: I will try to do so, if I remember well the backend developer said me that I should put a cookie

Comment: Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: servers don't have a "cookie" header in their responses - but they have a "set-cookie" header that gives you the cookie you need to set in your "cookie" header.  I updated my answer.  Also I'm not sure if the header names are case sensitive so you might want to print out the headers to see if it's `Set-Cookie`.

Comment: I changed my code with `"set-cookie"` , `"Set-Cookie"` and `"Set-cookie"`, but it says me: User not logged. Any other idea?

Comment: You are now correctly pulling out the correct header (Set-Cookie) but you are incorrectly storing the value in SharedPreferences (you are storing HeaderName+CookieValue as a cookie when all you need is the cookie value.  I updated my answer with a working implementation that should be all that you need.